# Exibindo posts do wordpress com curl

Tags: php, wordpress, libcurl

tem alguns sites onde a instalação do wordpress fica em uma subpasta chamada noticias e preciso exibir uma lista dos posts na index, pesquisando na internet vi que o wordpress gerava um JSON dos posts. Então dando mais uma vasculhada conseguir exibir, no entanto o método que eu estou usando é via "**file_get_contents**" do PHP, aí toda vez eu tenho que entrar no CPANEL e habilitar uma opção lá, devido a questões de segurança.

Foi quando um cara que tive contato disse que eu deveria usar **CURL**, aí vem a pergunta, como eu faço para pegar os pots e imagem de destaque?

Abaixo vou por o código que eu estou usando no momento que não é recomendada.

```html
   
<?php

$posts = file_get_contents('http://www.hospitalpadreze.org.br/noticias/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=2');
$obj = json_decode($posts);
foreach ($obj as $post) {
    $id = ($post->id);
    echo '<div class="box">';
    $thumbnail = file_get_contents('http://www.hospitalpadreze.org.br/noticias/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=' . $id . '');
    $images = json_decode($thumbnail);
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo '<div class="imagem-destaque">';
        echo '<a href="' . $post->link . '">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image->media_details->sizes->index_blog->source_url . '"/>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '<h2><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->title->rendered . '</a></h2>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim:

```
$ch = curl_init();  
$url = 'http://www.hospitalpadreze.org.br/noticias/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=2';
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$obj = json_decode($output);
foreach ($obj as $post) {
    $id = ($post->id);
    echo '<div class="box">';
    $thumbnail = file_get_contents('http://www.hospitalpadreze.org.br/noticias/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=' . $id . '');
    $images = json_decode($thumbnail);
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        echo '<div class="imagem-destaque">';
        echo '<a href="' . $post->link . '">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image->media_details->sizes->index_blog->source_url . '"/>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    echo '<h2><a href="' . $post->link . '">' . $post->title->rendered . '</a></h2>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```